# How to add leading zero when number is less than 10?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my sql table. I am wondering how can I add leading zero to my column when my column's value is less than 10? So for example:

```
number   result
1     ->    01
2     ->    02
3     ->    03
4     ->    04
10    ->    10
```

Comment: Generally, you should do this formatting at the presentation layer, not in the database layer.

Comment: what is the result if value is greater than 100 or 1000?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
format(number,'00')
```

Version >= 2012

Comment: This is a more elegant solution and it handles negative numbers

Comment: wait so only reason to not use this is if your sql server version is old as fack?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) FROM tbl
```

For `Number`s with length > 2, you use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Number BETWEEN 0 AND 99
            THEN RIGHT('0' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
        ELSE
            CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(10))
    END
 FROM tbl
```

Comment: @DragonBorn, This solution works great, but be aware that numbers wider than 2 digits are cut at 2 digits in any case. Might lead to strange errors...

Answer (score 4):

And yet one more solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@YourNumber,2),' ','0');
```

I prefer this, as other approaches might lead to random results in case of numbers which are wider than the count of digits you've specified:

But it will not deal with negativ numbers...

```
DECLARE @YourNumber INT=123;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@YourNumber,5),' ', '0')   --pad to five digits
      ,REPLACE(STR(@YourNumber,3),' ', '0')   --pad to 3 digits
      ,REPLACE(STR(@YourNumber,2),' ', '0');  --123 is wider than 2 digits...
```

The result

```
00123   
123 
**
```

Answer (score 2):

Felix's solution is great, unless you have numbers above 100 in your table, in which case, try using a case statement instead:

```
Select case when Number between 1 and 9 
    then '0' else '' end + cast(number as varchar(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

another method,

```
select case when number <10 then replicate('0',1)+cast(number as varchar) 
else cast(number as varchar) end
```

Comment: Why use `REPLICATE`? Why not just `'0'?

Comment: great @FelixPamittan ,you are right.if we have to repeat only one 0 then replicate won't be use but incase when 0 will be repeated then its fine.I just wanted to show different approach,it will help other user also.

Answer (score 0):

In another method, you can Replace 10 to 2.

```
declare @ID int =32123;

substring('000000000',1,10-len(cast(@ID as varchar(10)))) +   cast(@Id as varchar(10))
```

Result:
0000032123

Answer (score 0):

Formatting numbers to add leading zeros can be done in SQL Server. It is just simple. Lets create a new table and see how it works:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers(Num INT);
```

Lets insert few values and see

```
INSERT Numbers VALUES('12');
INSERT Numbers VALUES('112');
INSERT Numbers VALUES('12');
INSERT Numbers VALUES('122');
INSERT Numbers VALUES('122');
```

Now we can see how the numbers are formatted with 6 digits, if it has less than 6 digits it will add leading zeros.

```
SELECT * FROM Numbers;

Num
12
112
12
122
122
```

Formatting:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,Num),6) AS NUM FROM Numbers;

NUM
000012
000112
000012
000122
000122
```

OR

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Num), 6) AS NUM FROM Numbers;

NUM
000012
000112
000012
000122
000122
```

Answer (score 0):

Zeros can be added on left side using function **LPAD**

```
SELECT LPAD('123', 5, "0");
```

the result is the following

> 00123

**Syntax**

> LPAD(string, length, lpad_string)

```
SELECT LPAD(CustomerName, 30, "ABC") AS LeftPadCustomerName
```

FROM Customers;

**Result**

> LeftPadCustomerName

> ABCABCABCABAlfreds

Comment: SQL Server has no LPAD function, sorry

Comment: Its for mySQL
but for sql server You can use following
RIGHT(REPLICATE(pad_char, length) + LEFT(string, length), length)